# TFS Build Server with project with "custom build tool"

Tags: c++

I'm setting up an TFS 2010 Build server.
But I currently have the problem that projects with an "custom build tool" won't build because of "no access".

The projects are C++.

The custom build tool is "[Pro*C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro%2aC)". Basically, you have an *.pc file, and it generates an *.cpp file.
But on the build server, the directory/files are readonly. So it will crash on "no access".

I have tried to remove the *.cpp file from TFS. So that the generated file does not exists. But apparently the folder is also readonly and won't allow to create a new file.

Does anyone has a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of these options:

- Don't put the .cpp files in source control if they are generated by the build process
- Change the settings for Pro*C to write its output files to a writable intermediate folder
- Add a build step that copies the problem files to an intermediate location for processing
- Add a build step that forces the file access on those files to be readable for processing
- If you only need to build those files occasionally, then build them manually with Pro*C on your developer machine and check in the results, so you don't waste time unnecessarily rebuilding unchanging files with every desktop or build-server build.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called *MSBuild Community Tasks*, which can be downloaded from http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/. I used it for my own for an automated tfs-build.
It provides you with several extensions for your msbuild-project. One of this is the so called *Attrib* task, which gives you the opportunity to change file (and probably folder) attributes out of you project. It's not listed in the table on the website, but its documented in their documentation. As a sample from their documentation, you can add the following line to a target of your choice:

```
<Attrib Files="Test\version.txt" ReadOnly="true" Hidden="true" System="true"/>
```

I think this will also work for an item-group as follows

```
<Attrib Files="@(AllYourFiles)" ReadOnly="true" Hidden="true" System="true"/>
```

If you want to use it, don't forget to install it on the build server. ;)

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I need. But i'm not sure how I need to use it. Do I need to create a MSBuildTasks.proj myself, or does it exists somewhere?

Comment: The TFS build server 2010 doesn't use proj files (directly) anymore (unlike the TFS Build servers before). As you will have found out already, it uses Build-Templates, where all the build steps are defined. In the DefaultTemplate one of these steps is the invokation of msbuild. Normally, e.g. when creating a VS2010 Project, you will have such a project file(with the vcxproj-extension). You will have to create your own target in there and in this target you can place the commands from above. The other solution could be to create you own proj file and adapt the TFS Build Template to invoke it.

Comment: Do you have an idea if it is compatible with x64? I got it working on my dev machine, (win xp x86). But not on the server (win server 2k8 r2)

Comment: Could you please specify, what should be compatible with x64? The Project files are not restricted to x86 or x64. You also can choose in the build template settings what configurations should be build. So if you installed an x64 compiler on your build server, it should be no problem to generate x64 binaries.